# How to change button text in Laravel Nova?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

[image][![enter image description here][2]][2]

There is another screen shot, in which need to change ***no file selected*** text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Nova's built-in Laravel localization feature to change the name for relationship-oriented buttons. It is explained in the docs here: https://nova.laravel.com/docs/2.0/customization/localization.html#relationships

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the solution to above question today.

that is very simple.

Just add the translated text in auto-generated translation files from nova.

- When we install the nova, it will generate `resources/lang/vendor/nova` 
  translation directory.
- You can create your required lang file, like in my case, I need to add dutch translation so, I created the nl.json file.
- Simply override the text as shown below.

`{    "no file selected": "geen bestand geselecteerd" }`